# Is it safe to use Delphi visual form designer in high DPI?

Tags: delphi, dpi, form-designer, highdpi

In the past we were using standard 96dpi windows most of the time on developer machines, today it is common to go with 120 or even more.

Is it safe to save forms in Delphi in high dpi or are there any annoyances or risks involved?
I'm *not* asking how to do my application behave properly with different DPI modes - but asking if Delphi form designer is proven to work correctly in high dpi, so apps with the usual DPI handling techniques will work OK with forms saved with larger PixelsPerInch values.

Comment: *Is it safe to use Delphi visual form designer in high DPI?* Not if your forms have `Scaled` set to `True`. You'll get rounding errors and creep in dimensions as you open, modify and save forms.  Dev A uses 96dpi and makes one commit.  Dev B uses 120dpi and opens a form last modified by dev A, and then the IDE scales all the coords.  Then Dev B commits. Then dev A opens again and the coords are scaled down.  But not exactly to where we were before because of rounding to nearest integer.

Comment: Thanks, good point. And if all devs use 120 dpi, and we're having margins large enough, forms are structured with aligns, layouts and anchors so they are quite dynamic? So we only have scaling once when the end-user is running the software.

Comment: there is an attempt to somewhat ease the damage, but I did not tried it
https://github.com/delphinotes/BaseForms